# Make array value variable (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Say I want to echo an array but I want to make the value in the array I echo variable, how would I do this?

Below is kind of an explanation of what I won't to do but it isn't the correct syntax.

```
$number = 0;
echo myArray[$number];
```

Comment: Don't edit the question to fix the problem, it won't make sense if anyone ever references it in the future.

Comment: This is another piece of code that if they tried to actually run it, would throw an error, which might at least have put them onto the right track to fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. What you have isn't working because you're missing a `$` in `myArray`:

```
$myArray = array('hi','hiya','hello','gday');
$index = 2;
echo $myArray[$index]; // prints hello
$index = 0;
echo $myArray[$index]; // prints hi
```

Unlike other languages, [all PHP variable types are preceded by a dollar sign](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Answer (score 4):

Just to add more. Another type of array is associative array, where the element is determined using some identifier, usually string.

```
$arrayStates = array('NY' => 'New York', 'CA' => 'California');
```

To display the values, you can use:

```
echo $arrayStates['NY']; //prints New York
```

or, you can also use its numeric index

```
echo $arrayStates[1]; //prints California
```

To iterate all values of an array, use foreach or for.

```
foreach($arrayStates as $state) {
        echo $state;
}
```

Remember, if foreach is used on non-array, it will produce warning. So you may want to do:

```
if(is_array($arrayStates)) {
    foreach($arrayStates as $state) {
            echo $state;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No, you can not get the second value from an array with a numeric number. You have to use the key, though type conversion applies so '1' is equal to 1 as a key.

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly there:

```
$number = 0;
$myArray = array('a', 'b')
echo $myArray[$number];   // outputs 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = array("one","two","three","four");
$arrSize=sizeof($myArray);

for ($number = 0; $number < $arrSize; $number++) {
echo "$myArray[$number] ";
}

// Output: one two three four
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array('hi','hiya','hello','gday');

for($count=0;$count<count($myArray);$count++)
{
  $SingleValue = $myArray[$count];
  $AllTogether = $AllTogether.",".$SingleValue;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to add some notes explaining your answer.